# Load a drawable by name

Tags: android, android-resources

I have the following code:

```
if(d.getIcon() != null)
    {
        int resId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("cancel", "drawable","org.test.test.BouwSchermActivity"); 
        Drawable icon = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
        btn.setBackgroundDrawable(icon);
    }
```

This is my explorer:

[image]

When I run this, resId always returns 0.
If I use R.drawable.cancel instead of resId it works fine.

What could be the problem? 
I already tried to clean my project or use "cancel.png" instead of "cancel"

Thx :)

Comment: Is there acutally a problem? The whole point of the R file is so you can reference your resources very easily.

Comment: I needed it to be dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("package.name.name:drawable/cancel", null, null);
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(resId);
```